# Ruby module help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module

In the code below, I am able to call `BackgroundJob.starting(job_script)` just fine.  However, I keep getting no method error for starting when I try to call `JobScriptHelper.starting(RemoveBotReferralCodes)`, for example.  The `JobScriptHelper` is in the lib folder, while `RemoveBotReferralCodes` is in a peer folder called script. Any idea what's going on?

```
module JobScriptHelper

  def starting(job_script)
    puts "#{Time.now.strftime('%c')}: #{job_script.name} - starting"
  end

end



require 'job_script_helper'

    class BackgroundJob < ActiveRecord::Base

      extend JobScriptHelper

    end



#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require File.expand_path('../../../config/boot',  __FILE__)
require File.join(File.expand_path('../../../config/environment', __FILE__))
require 'job_script_helper'

class RemoveBotReferralCodes
  def self.remove
    # .... 
  end
end

JobScriptHelper.starting(RemoveBotReferralCodes)
```

Comment: shouldn't that be BackgroundJob.starting(RemoveBotReferralCodes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to call `JobScriptHelper.starting()` I believe your method definition should be

```
def JobScriptHelper.starting(job_script)
  puts "#{Time.now.strftime('%c')}: #{job_script.name} - starting"
end
```